# React classes in main component constructor

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Let's say I have a lot of app state to manage in my React application.
Therefore, I would like to split the state into smaller, manageable chunks.

For example I have the following main component with state and methods that alter this state.

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      foo: ['some', 'items'],
      bar: [{ arr: 'of objects'}]
    }
  }

  changeFoo() {some code in here...}
  changeBar() {some code in here...}
}
```

The state and methods written in the App component are getting out of hand. Yet it must be written in the App component since the state is passed to other components as props.
How would you usually manage this?

Answer (score 1):

When we see how React works. It is based on **one-directional data flow**.
So, usually the Application state is kept at the top most Component (Say, App Component) in your case. So that data/state can be passed down as **props** to the component that needs it.

There, however may be the cases where children components of the parent, needs to work with the same data(Say in case of an event - a button click that happens in the child component.) In that case we write a function in the parent component and **pass the function as props** to the children, so that the state gets updated in the parent itself and any child gets updated data.

[image: 1-way-data flow in React]

In **pure React** (without using any state management library), **we have to pass the state as props** to work with our app. But in case you choose to use a state management library such as **Redux**, then the components (known as **Containers**) can directly communicate with  the **Application State**.

And If your application state contains objects within objects(like you have shown) or Array of Objects containing more Objects, then you cannot use setState() to update the state directly. In most of the cases, you take copy of the state and then use **JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state)**) to do **deep cloning** and work with the state in a best possible manner.

There are other things in the example, the functions that you have used within the class , you need to bind the scope of this variable to point to the current class. This we do inside the constructor method, or simple make use of arrow function in order to avoid errors.

If you need more explanation, I will share with you :)

Comment: @Steve Winter There are other things, like the methods that you have used within the class , you need to bind the scope of this variable to point to the current class. This we do inside the constructor method, or simple make use of arrow function in order to avoid errors.

Answer (score 1):

When you see that the state of your React application is getting out of hand, it's usually time to bring in a *state management library* like [Redux](https://redux.js.org/) (there're a few and Redux is the most popular one).

It'll help you have a global state that is managed in a reasonable way.

Comment: That's what I thought, thank you I will look into it :) I have tried splitting the state into smaller chunks by creating classes for state data and methods on them. It works but I assume using a state management library must be the better solution.

Comment: Yes, Redux is really small in terms of lines of code, because it's more about guiding principles elaborated by Smart People than fancy tech :) Good principles are hard to find on your own, take the shortcut even if it seems cumbersome at first ^^

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to make a generic `change()` function with a parameter for the key that should be changed:

```
change(key, value) {
   setState({key: value, ...this.state});
}
```

Now when you want to add a listener to a child component:

```
<Foo onChange={ value => change('foo', value) }/>
<Bar onChange={ value => change('bar', value) }/>
```